# How to group by day of the year?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have following data for temperature for each date of the year

|  | ID | Date | Element | Data_Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | USW00094889 | 12/11/2014 | TMAX | 22 |
| 1 | USC00208972 | 29/04/2009 | TMIN | 56 |
| 2 | USC00200032 | 26/05/2008 | TMAX | 278 |
| 3 | USC00205563 | 11/11/2005 | TMAX | 139 |
| 4 | USC00200230 | 27/02/2014 | TMAX | -106 |

I aggregated that data for all the day from 2005 to 2015 for maximum and minimum for each days after filtering out leap year and data having 0 value with following code

```
dfMAX=df[(df['Element']=='TMAX') & (df['Data_Value']!=0) & (~df.Date.str.startswith('29/02'))].groupby("Date").agg({"Data_Value":np.max})
dfMIN=df[(df['Element']=='TMIN') & (df['Data_Value']!=0) & (~df.Date.str.startswith('29/02'))].groupby("Date").agg({"Data_Value":np.min})
```

Following were my output

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOsV7.png)

As you can see this returns the max for each date for each year. What I want to do is find the maximum and minimum value for each day over the range 2005-2014. My dates are in string format

Desired result:

| Day | Data_Value |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01 | # max for Jan 1st between 2005-2014 |
| 01-02 | # max for Jan 2nd between 2005-2014 |
| 01-03 | # max for Jan 3rd between 2005-2014 |
| 01-04 | # max for Jan 4th ... |

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html#rolling-window

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code based on your `dfMAX` dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['01/01/2005', '01/01/2006', '01/02/2005', '01/02/2006'], 'value': [1, 2, 4, 3]})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['day_and_month'] = df['date'].dt.day.astype(str) + '/' + df['date'].dt.month.astype(str)

df.groupby(['day_and_month'])['value'].max().reset_index()
```

Comment: When I apply it to dfMAX which was my grouped Dataframe, this does not work. I am getting KeyError :'Date'. To summarize, I have per day minimum and maximum temperature across many weather stations from 2005-2015. So first I created dfMAX by using Element='TMAX', Data_Value <>0 and date not starting with 29/02. Then I grouped by dates and aggregating Data_Value. dfMAX is result of this grouping. Now on this I want to futher group by days of the year so I can get just 365 rows. Hope this makes sense